# Securely receiving and passing Confidential information from jersey Web Service end

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey

We are developing Jersey based Rest Web services that receives input from a Mobile device. There are some sensitive parts of the JSON payload like Credit Card info, passwords and other things which needs to be passed over the wire. How can I ensure they are safely passed and received on the wire. By the way I am exposing my services as https. Is that just enough or do I need any other preventive measures.

Answer (score 0):

You may try client certificates. Get to know how servers present an SSL Cert when you send request server on https? Cervers can request a cert from a client so they know the client. Clients generate certs and give them to you over a secure channel.

You get public key of the cert client certificates into your server, and the web server won't accept connections from anyone except the people who have the corresponding private keys for the certs which server knows about.

Basically it runs on the `HTTPS layer`, so you may even be able to completely skip application-level authentication like OAuth (depending on your requirements). You can abstract a layer away and create a local Certificate Authority and sign Cert Requests from clients.

or further what you can do to secure your rest service; here is link to Owasp Security Lab which provides nice cheat sheet to do that: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/REST_Security_Cheat_Sheet